# uploading Axure exported html to wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess, axure

I would like to upload my Axure exported html (some javascript, css, and html files - all static content) to my wordpress site.
Now, I know I can simply connect with ftp and upload the folder to the hosted drive. But I'm not sure if that's the prefered method, what security issues are the to resolve (htaccess files??), and how to link to the mockup I made in my Axure in a frame (so it dynamically resizes).

Am I trying something that's just impossible, bad practice, ... Would I need to touch php? because my web knowledge goes as far as js/css... newbie too.

Help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any security concerns, or need to touch the htaccess file.

A sample of a wireframe I've shared and embedded in Wordpress is at: http://paulsizemore.com/4234-2/

Essentially, you need to add the references to the script files in the Wordpress content editor. You will need to add the web address to the href attributes of the tags.

[The Wordpress Content Editor View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtR65.png)

```html
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<link href="http://r4qr5p.axshare.com/resources/css/jquery-ui-themes.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://r4qr5p.axshare.com/resources/css/axure_rp_page.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://r4qr5p.axshare.com/LogIn_files/axurerp_pagespecificstyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link href="http://r4qr5p.axshare.com/LogIn_files/axurerp_pagespecificstyles_ie6.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  AXSHARE_HOST_URL = 'http://share.axure.com';
  AXSHARE_HOST_SECURE_URL = 'https://share.axure.com';
</script>
<script src="http://r4qr5p.axshare.com/data/sitemap.js"></script>
<script src="http://r4qr5p.axshare.com/resources/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://r4qr5p.axshare.com/resources/scripts/axutils.js"></script>
<script src="http://r4qr5p.axshare.com/resources/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://r4qr5p.axshare.com/resources/scripts/axurerp_beforepagescript.js"></script>
<script src="http://r4qr5p.axshare.com/resources/scripts/messagecenter.js"></script>
<script src='http://r4qr5p.axshare.com/LogIn_files/data.js'></script>

<!-- This is the iframe of the Axure Share URL --> 
<iframe src="http://r4qr5p.axshare.com/" width="800"></iframe>
```